# ByteBuddy static method interception @Origin method

Tags: java, byte-buddy

I have this static method intercepted correctly

```
 TypeDescription commandBase = TypePool.Default.ofClassPath()
      .describe("poo.laboratoire1.Q2.Application").resolve();
 new ByteBuddy()
      .redefine(commandBase, ClassFileLocator.ForClassLoader.ofClassPath())
      .method(named("obtenirTrame"))
      .intercept(MethodDelegation.to(Mock.class))
      .make()
      .load(ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader(),  
            ClassReloadingStrategy.Default.INJECTION);
```

but when I invoke the original method with this interceptor:

```
 public static boolean[] obtenirTrame(int i, @Origin Method origin){
     ...
    origin.invoke(null, i);
     ...
 }
```

I receive the new interceptor method in "origin" instead of the original method, resulting in an infinite recursion. Am I missing something or is this a bug ?

Answer (score 2):

By calling the `@Origin` method, you are invoking the same method that is currently executing. Byte Buddy instruments a method `foo` by changing a class:

```
class Bar {
  void foo() { /* some code */ }
}
```

into

```
class Bar {
  void foo() { Interceptor.call( ... ); }
  void foo$original() { /* some code */ }
}
```

You can use the `@SuperMethod` annotation, if you want to get hold of the original. It is however more recommended to use the `@SuperCall` or `@Morph` annotations.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot. Misunderstood the docs where it said : " Depending on the parameter's type, it is assigned a Method or Constructor reference to the original method ..."

Comment: However, I think my question was unclear as the original method named "obtenirTrame" is also static, so the suggested annotations throws : None of (...)  allows for delegation from private static boolean[] poo.laboratoire1.Q2.Application.obtenirTrame(int)